# How do I post in MongoDb collections using postman and express?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, postman

Im trying to insert / Post data in my mongoDb database using exrpess and through Postman, however im at loss in how to perform it. I defined an url being "/api/post" which executes a request of post and asks for now only the "title". When I use postman to create some data, it returns to me as "undefined" with an empty object.

Here is the code:

```js
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');

const express = require("express");

const mongoose = require("mongoose")

const app = express()

async function main() {
    
    const uri = "mongodb+srv://dbUser1:<password>@movies.uxfxv.mongodb.net/Movies?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

    const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

    const { schema } = mongoose;

  MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
    
        let dbo = db.db("Movies");
        dbo.collection("Movies").find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(result);
            app.get("/", (req, res) => {
                res.json(result)
            })

            app.post("/api/post", (req, res) => {
                const title = req.body
                console.log(title)
                res.json({
                    title
                })
            })
            
            db.close()
        })
    })
    
main().catch(console.error)
```

Here is the Postman Req.
[image]
I would appreciate any feedback an help, thanks!

Comment: The post request should return at lead the title field, can you paste an image of your postman request and response?

Comment: I would recommend to use either MongoDB or Mongoose for DB operations. I personally prefer mongoose as its easy to manage once the Schama has been defined. This should be  good example for mongoose schema creation an use with MongoDB - https://github.com/karan0405/rasp-host/blob/master/Node/app.js

Comment: I updated the post to show the response result